# Values submitted by a form with `multiple` in `bootstrap-select`

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

If one generates a form with `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-select`:

```
<form action="handle.php" method="post">
    <select name="pids" class="selectpicker" multiple>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="6">C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And one select all or multiple items, only the item with the last selected `value` is posted to the `handle.php` page.

**`handle.php`**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

result:

```
array(1) { ["pids"]=> string(1) "6" }
```

how can one retrieve all selected items?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Its most likely a case that you need to set the name to pids[] (note the square brackets) The square brackets define an array instead of a single value.

```
<select name="pids[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. I've made a pull request to update the documentation for `bootstrap-select`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<select name="pids[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>
```

Iam not sure but something like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note...even though this one is accepted since two years...

For this to work you must POST to a file (which makes it reload). I tried figuring it out for 5 hours.

But, if you want to use Ajax...then you can send all values by

```
var values_from_list=$('#id_of_the_field').val();
```

and it will send all to the little ajax array,
and in PHP you can json_encode it and save it to your db.

Hope it saves someone time.

Comment: You can send the form by AJAX, by serializing it, you don't have to specify every input in the form.